# Form framework doesn't render date type after ajax callback

Tags: datetime, forms

I have an ajax callback which returns a date type input field.

The problem is any other input type other than date is generated, but date type is not rendered at all. The title, and description is all generated, but the input field is not. Desperately, i have used the suffix tag to generate a date type field the good old html way. But i'm still concerned with if this is a bug or if im doing something wrong.

Here's the code

This one wont generate any fields, but will generate the title and description

```
function raffle_start_date_now($form, &$form_state)
{
    if($form_state['values']['raf_start_now'] == 0)
    {
        return  $form['raf_start_date'] = array(
                "#title" => "When to start this raffle?",
                "#description" => "Doesn't generate date input, but generates all other input",
                "#prefix" => "<div id='start_date_pick'>",
                "#suffix" => "</div>",
                "#required" => TRUE,
                "#type" => "date"
            );
    }
    else
    {
        return "<div id='start_date_pick'></div>";
    }

}
```

And changing the #type to "textfield" will render a textfield.

Currently, this is my workaround

```
function raffle_start_date_now($form, &$form_state)
{
    if($form_state['values']['raf_start_now'] == 0)
    {
        return  $form['raf_start_date'] = array(
                "#title" => "When to starz this raffle?",
                "#description" => "Doesn't generate date input, but generates all other input",
                "#prefix" => "<div id='start_date_pick'>",
                "#suffix" => "<input type='date' name='raf_start_date'/><br/></div>",
                "#required" => TRUE,
                "#type" => "date"
            );
    }
    else
    {
        return "<div id='start_date_pick'></div>";
    }

}
```

Comment: That AJAX callback is wrong. It's the form builder that changes the form element, not the AJAX callback. See the [various examples](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7) api.drupal.org has.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the examples really well and not able to implement them for my usage either. I really don't understand the part where i have to make the form builder change the form element. Especially when most of the examples i've seen use prefix and suffix to replace an entire input where as i just want to append one.

Comment: Also, you should show the form builder function, to get a more helpful answer. I am not sure what else we can add to the already existing examples, especially because you don't make clear what you don't understand.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I rewrote the form builder like this, its a tad bit ugly.

http://notey.it/n/dDN4